# Enviar datos a URL desde hook

Tags: reactjs, url

Tengo una consulta, al cargar una url, necesito pasarle información, la cual está en un hook.

```
const [tipo_de_usuario, set_tipo_de_usuario] = useState(0)

/* más código*/

  <div className="contenedor_central">
    <strong>Validación de e-mail correcta</strong>
    <IonButton href="/Completarinfo/${tipo_de_usuario}" >COMPLETAR INFORMACIÓN</IonButton>
  </div>
);
```

Ahora, al cargar la url `/Completarinfo` muestro por consola los datos suministrados y me pasa: `${tipo_de_usuario}` por lo que no está pasando la variable.

Así que estoy haciendo algo mal. ¿Podrían por favor indicarme la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal las comillas, si **[quieres concatenar variables dentro del mismo string](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)**, debes usar ***``***, por lo que esto debería solucionarlo

```
`/Completarinfo/${tipo_de_usuario}`
```

Nos comentas que tal te va!

Comment: Sigue con el mismo inconveniente:         <IonButton href='/Completarinfo/${tipo_de_usuario}'>COMPLETAR INFORMACIÓN</IonButton>

Comment: Pero son comillas inclinadas, no simples.

Comment: Además tengo entendido que si quieres realizar una redireccion debes usar `<IonButton (click)="tuFuncion()">COMPLETAR INFORMACIÓN</IonButton>`, no `href`

Comment: @JuliánOviedo si la respuesta fue la adecuada, no olvides marcarla como aceptada