# React JS params - Enviar datos a través de url

Tags: reactjs

En react js, paso información mediante una URL, luego intento obtener ese valor. Pero cuando lo muestro en consola me muestra lo siguiente:

> {tipo_de_usuario: ":1"}

Y yo necesito obtener el valor, el cual es 1. ¿Por qué es eso?

```
const CompletarInformacion = (tipo_de_usuario: any) => {

  const params = useParams();

  console.log(params);

/* sigue el código*/

}
```

Comment: Te resultó la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424139/enviar-datos-a-url-desde-hook/424167?noredirect=1#comment757473_424167) que te entregue? La idea del sitio es ir cerrando respuestas en base a que tanto sirvió o no una solución, y en el caso que no haya funcionado, que el OP entregue feedback para poder tener una mejor recepción de colegas que puedan tener el mismo problema que tú.

Comment: En cuanto a esta pregunta, puedes acceder al valor con un `params.tipo_de_usuario`. Al momento de realizar el `console.log` estas imprimiendo la estructura del objeto completa

Comment: Esto es lo que obtengo ¿Porque si el objeto dice que tiene esa propiedad?: Property 'tipo_de_usuario' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

Comment: Dónde te lanza ese error?

Comment: En el propio código de react js

Comment: Si, pero que línea...?

Comment: En esta linea el código me arroja error, sin compilar: console.log(params.tipo_de_usuario);
Property 'tipo_de_usuario' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

Comment: Será que necesitas realizar un _desglose_ en useParams; algo así, `const { tipo_usuario } = useParams()`